# Use 'this' to trigger a function when a Jquery tab is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tabs

I am creating Jquery Tabs dynamically by passing in a viewName parameter. I am trying to figure out how to use `this` to trigger another function based on the `id` of the dynamically created Tab.

Here is function that creates the Tabs and assigneds them an `ID` and Name dynamically.

```
function SetImportedView(viewName, scriptValue) {
/* put the values we received in parameters into create view tabs*/
$('<li id="' + viewName + '">' + '<a href="' + '#tabs-1' + '"</a>' + viewName +    '</li>').insertBefore('#new');
}
```

I need to trigger a another function that is specific to the `ID` of the Tab that is clicked.

something like this:

```
$(this.tab).click(function() {
 doSomething
}
```

Comment: Where is the code `$(this.tab)` coming from? Can't help you use the context object if we don't know the context.

Comment: @AndrewHubbs that was just an example. It does not exist. I am trying to figure out how I target an element that was created dynamically and I dont know the ID of it. Hope that makes sense

Comment: also jfyi I already intitailized tabs `$('#tabs').tabs()`

Answer (score 1):

What's with this

```
function SetImportedView(viewName, scriptValue) {
    /* put the values we received in parameters into create view tabs*/
    $('<li id="' + viewName + '">' + '<a href="' + '#tabs-1' + '"</a>' + viewName +    '</li>')
        .on( 'click', 'a' function( ev ) {
            // link in li clicked
         } )
        .insertBefore('#new');
}
```

#### edit

ok, you mean something like this?!?!

```
$( 'li' ).on( 'click', 'a', function( ev ) {
    var tabID = $( this ).parent().attr('id');

    // do something here with your tabID
} );
```

Comment: sorry, that does not seem to work. I will have many tabs created. After they are all created dynamically I will want to click on various tabs and trigger a function that looks at the tabs id as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

simply put an onclick on your "a" tag so it renders like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return myFunction();">TAB #1</a>
```

Comment: Tab-1 is a form template. All tabs go to this form block. The data inside the form is based on the tab that is clicked. I need to be able to determine which tab is clicked after all the tabs have been created.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

```
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: No need to wrap your element in jQuery for that, `$(this).attr('id')` is equivalent to `this.id`